# retrieve value from nested json into ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to get task name of array of tasks of jordan and jeremy. I need this

```
  <ul ng-repeat="relationship in user.relationship">
    <li ng-repeat="tasks in relationship.tasks.name">
        {{tasks.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and my nested json

```
var user = [
        {
        'uId': 1,
        'name': 'eldy',
        'relationship': 
            [
                {
                'uId':2,
                 'name': 'Jeremy',
                 'tabs':[{'tabId':1}],
                 'tasks':[
                    {'tabId':1,'name':'tasks 1 of Jeremy Lin'},
                    {'tabId':1,'name':'tasks 2 of Jeremy Lin'}
                 ],
                 'points': 50
                },

                {
                 'uId':3,
                 'name': 'Jordon',
                 'tabs':[{'tabId':2}],
                 'tasks':[
                    {'tabId':2,'name':'tasks 1 of Jordan'},
                    {'tabId':2,'name':'tasks 2 of Jordan'}
                 ],              
                 'points': 100
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

I'm confused to loop through array and object, since I can't console.log my markup, I always use trial and error method. Any better ways to debug when u do ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

user.relationship is undefined, you are actually trying to access user[0].relationship
the same principle will apply within relationship property, which is an array to iterate over.
`for rel in user[0].relationships`, iterate over `task in rel.tasks`.

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over `user`, then `relationship`, followed by `tasks`, and access the `name` property..

```
<div ng-repeat="user in user">{{user.name}}
  <ul ng-repeat="relationship in user.relationship">
    <li ng-repeat="task in relationship.tasks">
        {{task.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/numokero/2/edit

Try using the [Angular Batarang Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) to debug your angular models and bindings.

Comment: Originally I missed that `user` was itself an array that needed to be iterated. I figure that's what the downvote was for.

Comment: Yes. As adrichman suggested, you can use `ng-repeat="relationship in user[0].relationship"` to avoid the first loop. Although if you are only dealing with 1 user, I wouldn't expose a user array to the view. Instead, I would change the controller to say `$scope.user = user[0];` so that user is a single user object.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are more likely due to the fact that instead of recommending a `(key, value) in expression track by tracking_expression`, you created 3 sets of scopes using nested ng-repeats.  If you are nested ng-repeats just to drill into your data model... you're doing it wrong. and also because it creates a coupling so specific, it will only work in you have one total user object.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch Can you post an answer with what you're suggesting? We're all just trying to learn here. Thanks.

Comment: hey... I totally would or will if/when I figure it out.  Honestly... it's a good question, and so far you have the best answer.  I was just commenting on possible reasons for the downvotes.  This is one of those things the documentation doesn't really go into much detail on, so I'm picking apart the source.  So far I've improved on this using `track by` and `$index`, but not to the point to where I feel Angular is capable of.